# Kotlin scratch file seems using different Kotlin version from main app

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

### What I want to do

Hi :) I'm new to Kotlin. I want to use `kotlinx_serialization` in Kotlin scratch file.

### My environment

- IntelliJ IDEA: Build #IU-223.8214.52
- JDK 17 (temurin)
- Spring Boot 3.1.5
- macOS Ventura

### What Actually happened

[image]

Kotlin emits error: `The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.`

### The full error message

```
error: class 'kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/a202101054/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm/1.6.0/94b35f721f1029b3b8d46fb277b4e53fb1a0a510/kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/kotlinx/serialization/ExperimentalSerializationApi.class
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
                             ^
error: class 'kotlinx.serialization.Serializable' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/a202101054/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm/1.6.0/94b35f721f1029b3b8d46fb277b4e53fb1a0a510/kotlinx-serialization-core-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/kotlinx/serialization/Serializable.class
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
                             ^
error: unresolved reference: encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
                             ^
error: class 'kotlinx.serialization.json.Json' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/a202101054/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm/1.6.0/59761a941bd8691b3ef2447f5b9376868a6b2d7e/kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/kotlinx/serialization/json/Json.class
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
                                  ^
error: class 'kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonNamingStrategy' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.
The class is loaded from /Users/a202101054/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm/1.6.0/59761a941bd8691b3ef2447f5b9376868a6b2d7e/kotlinx-serialization-json-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/kotlinx/serialization/json/JsonNamingStrategy.class
import kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonNamingStrategy
                                  ^

error: unresolved reference: ExperimentalSerializationApi
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
       ^

error: an annotation argument must be a compile-time constant
@OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
       ^
```

### Additional Configuration

[image]

[image]

[image]

my `build.gradle.tks`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    id("com.diffplug.spotless") version "6.19.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.8.22"

    // json
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.20"
}

group = "wesang.sample"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

spotless {
    kotlin {
        ktlint()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")

    // Mysql
    runtimeOnly("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j")


    implementation(platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.4"))
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")

    // redis (lettuce)
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis")

    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
//    runtimeOnly("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-datadog")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

### My Question

Could you guys please let me know what am I doing wrong? I'm Python developer new to Kotlin

Comment: Can you add your `gradle` files ? Both `:module` and `:app` could help. Also your `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Comment: @ItzDavi sure! I added them

Comment: some other articles says to increase `ext.kotlin_version`. but i don't have that in my build.gradle.kts file. should I add one ?

Comment: Downgrade your kotlin version from 1.9.0 to 1.7.1, it should be fine after.

Comment: thanks for the reply! @ItzDavi, but I want to upgrade rather than downgrade. is there a way to do upgrade? plus, how to do downgrade?

Comment: Can you try to update your IDE and check the problem?

Answer (score 0):

From [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#gradle) GitHub's readme:

Kotlin DSL

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0" 
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
}
```

And

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.0")
}
```

Update your "jvm" and "plugin.serialization" to version 1.9.0.

#### EDIT:

I downloaded a basic Spring project from [here](https://start.spring.io/).

[image: Spring Initializr]

I then checked all my files and yours, and there are some differences.

[image: Kotlin compiler settings]

I use the bundled `Kotlin` version from the IDE, setting also to `1.9` the `Language version` and the `API version`. Note also that the `Target JVM version` is `1.8`.

In the Project Structure settings, tho, you can see both `Kotlin` versions are set to `1.8`

[image: Project structure settings]

This is my `build.gradle.kts`

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.3"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.22"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.bootBuildImage {
    builder.set("paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest")
}
```

And this is `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

If nothing above works, I would try creating a completely new Spring project from the [initializr](https://start.spring.io/) or IDEA directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but It didn't solved. but the error message has changed. `The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.7.1.` seems like binary version has changed. how do i change the expected version?

Comment: @Jerry did you use https://start.spring.io/ to generate your project ?

Comment: I created the project in IDEA directly. and also I initialized the project like you suggested... and tried again but had no luck... same error. I have no clue where the `expected version is 1.7.1` comes from